# Can someone please help me to identify this plant?

Tags: trees, leaves, flowers

I found this plant in Rio de Janeiro, Brazil. It looks to be a tree with purple flowers.[Tree with purple flowrs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0clg.jpg)

[image: Purple flowers]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a *Tibouchina*, possibly *T. mutabilis*, though its name has recently changed to *Pleroma mutabile*. It's a tree that grows in hotter regions, and often has a few white flowers mixed in with the purple ones. It can reach up to 12 metres in height over time https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleroma_mutabile